# Multi-device hybrid apps: why <vs:feature> tag?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

In the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx there is explained how to add a plugin including its version. Why is a new  tag invented while Cordova has support for plugins and versions using **cordova save plugins** and **cordova restore plugins**. See also http://www.gorkem-ercan.com/2014/06/sharing-cordova-projects-becomes-easier.html. I know this is still an experimental feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vs:feature` tag was added to the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps project to support plugins. At the time MDHA had its CTP 1.0 release, the save/restore feature had not yet been proposed in the Cordova community and, like you said, is currently still in its experimental stages.